Shadow a Cube with body diagonal along y axis
We have a cube with its body diagonal (greatest diagonal joining two opposite vertices) aligned along the y axis. Thus, the cube stands on one vertex with the opposite vertex directly above it.
The light source is directly above along the y axis at infinite distance. What will be the shape and side lengths of the projected area?
I think it will be a hexagon but am unsure if it is a perfectly regular hexagon or an irregular one.

I’m sure it’s a regular hexagon but I don’t have a handy proof for that. I’m sure someone will respond with a proof.
